# MKPolygonView fillcolor property is not working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Below is the code that is not working in some cases. I just need to know the possible reasons for this.
Problem : .`fillcolor` property is not working some times polygon is not filled by any color but the border property is working fine.

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id )overlay
{
    NSLog(@"inside the viewForOverlay delegate");

    NSLog(@"draw polygon inside the viewForOverlay delegate");
    //for draw polygon---
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]]) {
        MKPolygonView* v = nil;
        v = [[[MKPolygonView alloc] initWithPolygon:(MKPolygon*)overlay]
             autorelease];

                v.lineWidth = 10;
                v.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1];
                v.fillColor = [[UIColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1];
        return v;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: How many polygons and how many points in each polygon?  Make sure that the points/coordinates in each polygon are listed in the proper order.

Comment: @AnnaKarenina thanks for the reply. I debug my code and found only 1 polygon with 44 points.Can you tell me how to check that the coordinates are in proper order.

Comment: The map view draws the polygon in the exact order the points are given so make sure the points follow the outline of the polygon instead of jumping from one side of the polygon to another.  If they are out of order, it can produce drawing issues.  Try including only the first 20 points and see if it draws ok then increase or decrease until the problem starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer fill color is working but it only fills the area enclosed in it. So the which the polygon draws in is very small so it hides in the with of the line of the polygon.